# Trying to create something like MyClass<T> : UserControl in UWP - possible? If so, how?

Tags: c#, generics, user-controls, uwp, windows-10

I'm working with UWP on Windows 10 and I have a custom UserControl, MyControl; My life would be a LOT easier if I could do this for the code-behind of MyControl:

```
public partial class MyControl<T> : UserControl
{
 //stuff
}
```

and then specify T in the XAML.

Can I do that in UWP, and if so, what is the syntax?

FYI, the main reason for this is that we want MyControl to be able to serve as the view for several different ViewModels that can't be unified by a non-generic parent class or interface (they do inherit from a parent class, but it looks like this: `MyParentClass<T>` )

If I can't get this to work, I'm going to have to create an entire second copy of MyControl with about 5 lines different from the original, which is a maintenance nightmare.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is possible. But instead you can have a type property.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to use generic type in user control. If you don't want to create a second copy of "MyControl", use reflection instead.